# How do I configure aws ec2 security groups to allow ssh from a hotspot connected mac

Tags: ssh

I cannot connect my mac laptop to ssh through an iphone hotspot.  Normally I set the ec2 instance security group to just allow my ip which I find with whatsmyip.org.  But with the hotspot connected mac this does not work. If I open up the security group port to all incoming IPV4 traffic I can connect.  Is there a way to ssh through a hotspot connected mac?

Comment: did you find how to do this?